# how to avoid page jquery for each page hanging

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
$.each(dataresp, function(key,val){
        cnt=cnt+1;
        var idval=cnt+"_content";
        var str = '<div id="'+idval+'"></div>'
         $(".Container").append(str);
         myProcessMethod(idval);// in this method I used to fill the above div with content
    }); 


when there is too much data , html page is not showing . browser page got freeze until the loop finishes.
```

once after completing loop, able to see the page.
    how to avoid freezing. ie. showing data in browser page after completing one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a document fragment, append your elements there, and then append the fragment to the DOM.

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

$.each(dataresp, function(key,val){
         cnt=cnt+1;
         var idval=cnt+"_content";
         var d = document.createElement('div');
         d.id = idval;
         docFrag.appendChild(d);
         myProcessMethod(idval);// in this method I used to fill the above div with content
    }); 

$(".Container").append(docFrag)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(dataresp, function(key,val){
        _.defer(function(){
            cnt=cnt+1;
            var idval=cnt+"_content";
            var str = '<div id="'+idval+'"></div>'
            $(".Container").append(str);
            myProcessMethod(idval);
       });
    })
```

defer is a function of underscore,just an aliase of `setTimeout(fn,0)`,
frontend js,all heavy function should run as defer.

Comment: hi jefers , Tried, working, page loads but scroll hangs untill the full page got finished

Comment: At starting of render,calculate the total height and set the container's height.